# ASP.NET Core 6 JWT authentication fails with error code 401 - unauthorized in browser but not in Postman

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I'm trying to implement simple authentication system using JwtBearer. It works as expected using Postman, I get generated token and can access restricted areas annotated with [Authorize], but in browser I always get error with code 401 Unauthorized. What I'm doing wrong?

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Jwt": {
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:5165/",
    "Audience": "https://localhost:5165/",
    "Key": "topsecrettoken"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"]
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Path}/{action=Index}");

app.Run();
```

**GenerateJsonWebToken method**

```
private string GenerateJsonWebToken(UserModel user)
{
    var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName!),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email!),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName!),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName!),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.Role!)
    };

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
        _config["Jwt:Audience"],
        claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(1),
        signingCredentials: credentials
    );

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

**Test JWT method**

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[Route("auth")]
public IActionResult AuthTest()
{
    return Ok("Authenticated with JWT!");
}
```

**Postman**
[image]

[image]

However, when I do AJAX call with

```
headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + jwt
}
```

I get what I want. The problem persists when I navigate to another page. This means - key is the headers and JSON Web Token is not passed.

Comment: I have the same issue now. Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. For MVC controllers I had to add in

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
});

...

app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseSession();
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var JWToken = context.Session.GetString("JWToken");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(JWToken))
    {
        context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + JWToken);
    }
    await next();
});
```

**API login controller**

```
private IHttpContextAccessor _context;

public LoginController(IConfiguration config, IHttpContextAccessor context)
{
    _config = config;
    _context = context;
}

...

var token = GenerateJsonWebToken(user);
_context.HttpContext.Session.SetString("JWToken", token);
```